Excel VBA - deleting sheet leaves phantom sheet object in object browser
So, I'm using a macro to automate a tedious data manipulation process on a large data set.  As part of this I take a pre-existing calculated sheet, let's say "Output", and create a new sheet called "Output_Final" which will contain the updated data.
I check to see if "Output Final" exists, and if it does I delete and re-create it.  This works fine in terms of physically replacing the actual sheet.  However in the object browser I see a heap of phantom Sheet objects (apologies for the rubbish picture quality):

I'm deleting sheets using the following method, although the sheet name is parameterised:
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output_Final").Delete
Am I missing something obvious?  I'm still developing this solution so there will be a heap more test runs to do, and users will re-run frequently so I don't really want hundreds of phantom objects hanging around.  Apart from anything else the initial default sheet name being generated increments each time and I don't know if there's a limit.

Please share more detail: the complete code, how many sheets there are, and their names. If the code in the same workbook, use ThisWorkbook instead of ActiveWorkbook.

This can happen if the objects aren't fully released from memory. After deleting the sheet, explicitly set the sheet object to Nothing to release it from memory:
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output_Final")
ws.Delete
Set ws = Nothing

See also Remove a non-existant Sheet in VBA, VBA code deletes it's own sheet, leaving a "ghost" sheet behind, GHOST Worksheet in Project Explorer - How to Delete It?

Thank you :)  Sorry I can't upvote due to being a newbie.

@Amanensia - you should be able to click the tick for accepting the answer.  Will give Michal some kudos and show the question has been answered.

Done, apologies.
